# PYINSTALLER - EXE file don't loud the program - MISSING MODULES

Tags: python, pyinstaller

You can find my project on https://github.com/Ivanchukk/Book_app
This is Tkinter app that allowing lots of writers work on the same book.
It have 4 py files and 2 db files.

The command i input to cmd is:

```
pyinstaller -y -i "/PycharmProjects/book_app/exe/Books_icon.ico" --add-data "/PycharmProjects/book_app/exe/book_db.db";".db" --add-data "/PycharmProjects/book_app/exe/login_db.db";".db" --add-data "/PycharmProjects/book_app/exe/image/login.ico";".ico" --add-data "/PycharmProjects/book_app/exe/image/register.ico";".ico"  "/PycharmProjects/book_app/exe/login.py"
```

When I run pyinstaller it create all the folders and exe file but when I run the program nothing happens.
So I went to warn-login text file and got the this errors:

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported from within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
           yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (conditional)

missing module named org - imported by copy (optional)

missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed)

missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional)

missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level)

missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)

missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional)

missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional)

missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional)

missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)

missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)

missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)

missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional)

missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional)

excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional)

missing module named console - imported by pyreadline.console.ansi (conditional)

missing module named startup - imported by pyreadline.keysyms.common (conditional), 

pyreadline.keysyms.keysyms (conditional)

missing module named sets - imported by pyreadline.keysyms.common (optional)

missing module named System - imported by pyreadline.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard (top-level), 

pyreadline.keysyms.ironpython_keysyms (top-level),
 pyreadline.console.ironpython_console (top-level),
 pyreadline.rlmain (conditional)
missing module named StringIO - imported by pyreadline.py3k_compat (conditional)

missing module named IronPythonConsole - imported by pyreadline.console.ironpython_console (top-level)

missing module named clr - imported by pyreadline.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard (top-level), 

pyreadline.console.ironpython_console (top-level)

missing module named KeyValidator - imported by book_1 (top-level)

missing module named dominio - imported by \PycharmProjects\book_app\exe\login.py (top-level)
```

Do you have any idea what should I do?

Comment: Your repo is missing e.g. `dominio` and `KeyValidator` modules, to begin with.

Comment: Also, the images your pyinstaller command line refers to are also missing from the repository, making things impossible to reproduce for others.

Comment: @AKX Thank you for the replay. What is repo? And how or where should I install the missing modules?
What information should I add so you will be able to understand the problem?

Comment: With "repo" I mean your GitHub repository. Your code seems to be importing things from something called "dominio" and "KeyValidator" which do not exist there; if they're external libraries you've installed with e.g. pip, you should list them so people know how what to do to run your program.

Comment: Similarly, if you expect people to be able to run that pyinstaller command to help you, we will also need those image resources; they're not on GitHub either.